# Site content type not appearing in Site Contents

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

I am quite new to sharepoint and I am starting however I created a list of items that right now has only two items because I am testing.

The problem that I have is that when I go to "Site contents" I cannot see the list I just created, I have to go back to "site settings", "Web Designer Galleries" and "Site Content Types" in order to see my list.

Can anyone tell me why does this happen and how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you please share some snapshots if possible. from the description you have provided is not sufficient to answer

Comment: @SigarDave what I mean is, if I create a site content type inheriting from List and item. Why cant I see my content type as a list, how do I use it???

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you have created a content type which is inherited from List and item content types. And you want them to appear when you try to create a new list correct?

Comment: @SigarDave yeah, what I want to understand is why if my new type is a list, I cannot see it with the rest of my list objects.